# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'typeDict'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to install TensorFlow in Python. I am getting the following error message, I tried uninstalling NumPy and re-installing NumPy but still getting the same error message. How to resolve this issue?

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'typeDict'
```

Comment: What versions are you using, `numpy` etc.  This may be too soon to use numpy 1.24.  Other packages might not have adjusted to the changes, especially the deprecated features.

Comment: I just posted a solution that does not involve degrading the version of any library, check it out.

Answer (score 62):

I was trying to use the package pyensembl and ran into this same issue. I was able to work around it for now with

```
pip install numpy==1.21
```

Which should suffice until some of these less active packages are able to update to the new API.

Comment: this fixes  the issue with tensorflow's dependencies, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

As we can see in [NumPy 1.21.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/tag/v1.21.0)

> `np.typeDict` is a deprecated alias for `np.sctypeDict` and has been so
> for over 14 years
>
> ([6689502](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/668950285c407593a368336ff2e737c5da84af7d)).
>
> A deprecation warning will now be issued whenever getting `np.typeDict`.
>
> ([gh-17586](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/17586))

This means you are using a NumPy version that removed the deprecated ways AND the library you are using wasn't updated to match that version (uses something like `np.typeDict` instead of `np.sctypeDict`).

You have at least three options now

1. [Report the issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues?q=is%3Aissue+typedict) and wait until it gets fixed by TensorFlow.
2. Use an older version of `numpy` (one before it started to issue the deprecation warning) and wait for it to be fixed.
3. Change `np.typeDict` to `np.sctypeDict` wherever is being used.

Answer (score 7):

For me `pip install numpy==1.21` created more problems,

I resolved it by using '1.22.1' version

Answer (score 6):

I did get this exact error while trying to import TensorFlow after installation, but I was able to get around this by upgrading the `h5py` library. There is no need to degrade the NumPy library, as doing so might cause compatibility issues with other libraries that rely on the upgraded version.

```py
pip install --upgrade h5py
```

If you check the error message well, you will notice these lines, which state the possible causes:

```py
File “h5py\h5t.pxd”, line 14, in init h5py.conv
File “h5py\h5t.pyx”, line 293, in init h5py.h5t
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\numpy_init.py", line 320, in getattr
raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute ")
```

The solution that does not involve degrading any library is to upgrade the `h5py` library.

Comment: Upgrading h5py worked for me as well.

I did `conda install -c conda-forge h5py=3.9`

Comment: Exactly, but it will still work without specifying the `h5py` version `conda install -c conda-forge h5py`.

Comment: This worked for me. Before, importing `keras_tuner` did not only get a depration warning, but an error that caused the scrpit to stop. This did the trick, now running on numpy 1.24.3 without issues

Answer (score 1):

Spacy still hasnt upgraded to latest numpy versions. I degraded numpy to 1.21 and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was caused by having an older version of matplotlib. After updating, the error went away:

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I restarted the kernel and the issue was gone. Try restarting your kernel if you have the correct version of tensorflow and numpy.

Answer (score 0):

You have to degrade your Numpy and pandas version, everything depends on the version that tensorflow supports.
No other solution for now

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by upgrading the scipy package to 1.10.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a conda environment with Python `3.9.12`, numpy was in version `1.25.0`.

I solved the problem by updating Keras with:

```
conda update keras
```

Keras version was `2.10.0`. After gathering the kernel everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error "module 'numpy' has no attribute 'typeDict'" after I installed a new version of `Numpy`. I was using Scipy for my project, and I found a message related to Scipy when I loaded `Scipy`, like `from scipy.optimize import least_squares` in the project.

My solution to this error is to update the mismatch packages that depend on Numpy, which is to run the following:

`pip install --upgrade scipy`

If you are using other packages that depend on Numpy, please check the error messages and upgrade these packages that may help you to fix this problem. Hope this also works for you.

Best wish.

Answer (score 0):

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 7
5 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # biblioteca para o pré processamento de textos
6 import random # números aleatórios
----> 7 import seaborn as sns #  para geração de gráficos
8 import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot # para gráficos tb

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/**init**.py:5
3 from .utils import *  # noqa: F401,F403
4 from .palettes import *  # noqa: F401,F403
----> 5 from .relational import *  # noqa: F401,F403
6 from .regression import *  # noqa: F401,F403
7 from .categorical import *  # noqa: F401,F403

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py:21
13 from .utils import (
14     adjust_legend_subtitles,
15     _default_color,
(...)
18     _scatter_legend_artist,
19 )
20 from ._compat import groupby_apply_include_groups
---> 21 from ._statistics import EstimateAggregator, WeightedAggregator
22 from .axisgrid import FacetGrid, _facet_docs
...
318     return Tester
--> 320 raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
321                      "{!r}".format(**name**, attr))

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'typeDict'

I was having this problem and was solved upgrading the scipy package to 1.10.1.