# well i am trying to "import tensorflow as tf "

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

getting an error in it. I have tried to ask chatgpt as well but well it has run out of solutions. I tried down grading the libraries and also upgrading a few but it still didn't solve my error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRgMT.png)

well I am trying to build a project in jupyter note book and yeah , seems like I have hit a wall

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74852225/attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-typedict)

1. Install the numpy 1.21.1

OR

2. modify the code in tensorflow. Change 'typeDict' to its new alias

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, including the bullet point regarding questions previously asked-and-answered, and those lacking specific details (in evaluating the latter, note that [screenshots don't count as content "included in the question"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)).